# How to get data from a list field in Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am using a `ListView.builder` to show the data of all the documents on one page in my app. So, how can I make a `ListView` inside a `ListView` to show all data of the internal array called drinks?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this with FutureBuilder if you want.

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('yourCollectionPath')
                    .doc('yourDocPath')
                    .get(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData &&
                      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    var data = snapshot.data.data();
                    var drinks = data['drinks'];

                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: drinks.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Text(drinks[index].toString());
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text("Error");
                  }
                },
              ),
```

I have to mention that there are so many way to handle with this situation. This one is the simplest way.

Comment: all the collection documents is showen by a list view not only one document the solution you have made can be used for a one document so please how to make the solution work with all documents at once

Comment: var drinks = data['drinks']; // as you can see i just take your 1 field. You can create a custom model class for all fields or you can achive your other fields like this data['fields']. But if you don't know how to model fields with custom model class let me know that.

Comment: Yes i don’t know how to model fields with custom model class can you help ? ❤️

Comment: I am on a trip for a while im gonna reply this for you in a few day.